# Are there any computer readable corpora for ASL?

Tags: corpora, resource-request, sign-languages, asl

I'm looking to see if there are any free-to-use corpora in ASL (any domain is fine), transcribed so a computer can use it.

I am interested in doing some analysis on ASL syntax, morphology etc. But I have not found anything yet.

(If you know any computer-readable corpora  for other sign languages, I'd be interested in that as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply googling "ASL corpus" gives several results:

ASL:

- [National Center for Sign Language and Gesture Resources (NCSLGR) Corpus](http://www.bu.edu/asllrp/ncslgr-for-download/download-info.html)
- [ASL Motion-Caputure Corpus](http://latlab.ist.rit.edu/corpus/)

Other sign languages:

- [CAVA (British Sign Language Corpus)](http://www.bslcorpusproject.org/cava/)
- [Corpus NGT (Sign Language of the Netherlands)](http://www.ru.nl/corpusngtuk/)
- [Auslan Corpus (Australian Sign Language)](http://www.auslan.org.au/about/corpus/)
- [overview of corpora from different sign languages](http://www.sign-lang.uni-hamburg.de/dgs-korpus/index.php/sl-corpora.html)